# I keep hearing the word "fresh meat" in Roblox Studio when creating game

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this problem in studio (not game) that's extremely weird. It doesn't occur in Roblox studio when there is only one person in the Roblox Studio. It only happens when there are two or more people and Team Create in switched ON. Once you get up to a certain point, you will start hearing the words "fresh meat," and it doesn't go away. The sound: https://robloxsong.com/song/4518440176-ahh-fresh-meat, I've looked at everything that produces sound in explorer, but it doesn't match the sound I'm hearing. This problem the same from post: https://www.reddit.com/r/robloxgamedev/comments/c76bp1/i_keep_hearing_the_word_fresh_meat_in_my_game/ but author don't write any answer for this. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I mean based on the reddit discussion, it is a self-replicating script that got into your system. the 3rd post down seems good for diagnosing if you have some "soundjack" or some other unknown scripts running

Comment: It also sounds like you could havea plugin that's playing sounds every so often. Take a look at your installed plugins in the Plugin Management widget and try disabling them, then see if the sounds are still playing.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a virus in your game. What I like to do is use this plugin to scan for viruses.

https://www.roblox.com/library/1405499408/RoDefender.

Comment: Defender plugins are what cause the issues in-game 95% of the time.

Comment: @Tyler2P, Why??

Comment: Plugins can execute code in both the Edit and Play modes, so plugins that say they catch viruses can also execute the same kinds of exploits they claim to protect against. Always be careful about which developers you download plugins from. TylerP's comment is in reference to the fact that there are copycats who will mimic a real defender plugin, but have it create backdoors and other exploits at the same time.